# Enough MVC to be dangerous

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-5

I have built and EF5 model of my DB and have it in a separate project that I reference in my MVC project. I have several controllers and associated views to allow the data in the model to be rendered view razor to the UI. When it comes to editing a record, there are some foreign key relationships as show in the attached model diagram.
[image]

I can see the data in the index view and am able to navigate to the create view as shown below:

[image]

[image]

However, the drop down that contains the list of vendors only shows the first property from the vendor object. This is not what I want the view to do.

My GET and POST code look like this:

```
    //
    // GET: /Property/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.PropertyType = new SelectList(db.PropertyTypes, "Id", "PropertyTypeName");
        ViewBag.VendorID = new SelectList(db.Vendors, "ID", "Title");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Property/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Property property)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Properties.Add(property);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.PropertyType = new SelectList(db.PropertyTypes, "Id", "PropertyTypeName", property.PropertyType);
        ViewBag.VendorID = new SelectList(db.Vendors, "ID", "Title", property.VendorID);
        return View(property);
    }
```

and my view razor code looks like this:

```
@model Model.Property
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Property</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyNumber)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyStreet)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyStreet)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyStreet)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyTown)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyTown)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyTown)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyPostcode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropertyPostcode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyPostcode)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyType, "PropertyType1")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("PropertyType", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PropertyType)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VendorID, "Vendor")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("VendorID", string.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VendorID)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Can anyone help me with the solution to change the property being shown in the dropdown to a different one (I have created a calculated field in the model as I thought that might be easier to display as the value for the dropdown) or a concatenation of the other name fields shown in the model in the create action of the controller so the view move information in the dropdown list?

Many thanks,

Jason.

EDIT

I have now changed my create action to the following as suggested:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.PropertyType = new SelectList(db.PropertyTypes, "Id", "PropertyTypeName");

        ViewBag.VendorID = new SelectList(db.Vendors.Select(v => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = v.ID,
            Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", v.Title, v.Firstname, v.Secondname)
        }), "Text", "Value");

        return View();
    }
```

But now it won't compile. The m.id property I'm trying to assign to Value is an int (it's the primary key of the vendors table) but I can't cast it to a string otherwise the Razor engine raises an error when the view is rendered.

Any more ideas or help about how to overcome this apparently simple task.

Thanks again.

J.

Comment: You need to provide your get method and your view code.

Comment: Additional code added.

Comment: Agreed. The problem is how you're building your dropdown list for `Vendor`, but it's impossible to say what that problem is without being able to see it.

Comment: Chris's answer is correct.  However, you have another problem.  Your code won't postback properly because you're not creating your dropdownlist correctly.  MVC's dropdownlist helper does not work correctly when you post if the List of items is the same name as your selected item.  Yes, it populates correctly on the get.. but you will start getting weird errors when you post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dropdown list is showing exactly what you told it to show.

```
ViewBag.VendorID = new SelectList(db.Vendors, "ID", "Title", property.VendorID);
```

You're telling it to use the `Title` property of the `Vendor` object for the display text. If that's not what you want, then specify another property. If you want a combination of properties, such as first and last name, you'll have to construct your `SelectList` using `SelectListItem`s:

```
ViewBag.VendorID = new SelectList(db.Vendors.Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = m.ID,
        Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", m.FirstName, m.LastName)
    }, "Value", "Text", property.VendorID);
```

Comment: Chris. I get a build error on Value = m.ID since value expects a string and m.ID is a int. If I cast m.ID to m.ID.ToString() I get a runtime error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I'm constantly making that mistake until intellisense reminds me I'm stupid. Yes, it should be `Value = m.ID.ToString()`. I'm not sure why you're getting a runtime error with that, but something else is causing that error.

Comment: ViewBag.VendorID = new SelectList(db.Vendors.ToList().Select(m => new SelectListItem
    {...

Worked ok once .ToList() was added.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Html.DropDownList("VendorID", (SelectList)ViewBag.VendorID)

@Html.DropDownList("PropertyType", (SelectList)ViewBag.PropertyType)
```